# wp-admin: Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

So im having some problems to login after tranfer from Windows hosting to Unix.

When im trying to login to admin panel i see this:

```
Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page
```

I have used google, search and etc. All what was written in posts doing for me nothing, like disable plugins, change theme and so on, im still having this problem. I have asked hosting company, they have told me this:

```
The problem is caused by the fact that you created multisite and most likely made confusion in the privileges. You'd better turn to the wordpress programmer
```

But the thing is that i have not created multisite, only installed the language plugin(WPML).

DEBUG and error showing me nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically permission issue.

You need to do the following,

```
find foldername -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find foldername -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

Change the files permission to correct ones , 644 for files and 755 for folders.

Comment: For the user of for the folders/files?

Comment: Check here : https://askubuntu.com/questions/6723/change-folder-permissions-and-ownership

Comment: I will ask hosting to make that. Might be, but not sure.

Comment: They have already made that, but still im having that problem.